# Strange regex issues

Tags: javascript, regex

The regular expression I am using is returning too much text.  The expression is supposed to strip out a name and date from the text.

```
var sCurrentText = "(26 JAN 2011) - ILewis Provided excellent translation.";
var sRegxDate    = "\([0-9]{2}[\\\.\/\-, ](Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[\\\.\/\-, ][0-9]{4}\)[, \-]{0,3}[A-z]+ ?\-?\:? ?";
var DatePattern  = new RegExp(sRegxDate, "i");
var sDate        = DatePattern.exec(sCurrentText);
alert(sDate);
```

I expect:

```
(26 JAN 2011) - ILewis
```

But the popup says:

```
(26 JAN 2011) - ILewis,JAN
```

Other annoying issues:

1. I am not able to emulate this issue in regexpal. http://regexpal.com/

2.

```
alert(sDate[0]);
```

returns:

```
(26 JAN 2011) - ILewis
```

but

```
oTextbox.value = sDate[0];
```

results in an empty textbox.  Frustrating.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the original string? Can you post that?

Comment: I don't think that you have to escape the characters inside a character class... put the '-' (which would otherwise be interpreted as a range) directly after the opening brace, then list out the other characters in the class: `[-./\, ]`. That may also explain part of the problem, because the regex engine may bee seeing `\-,` as the range between `\` and `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are alerting `sDate` thinking that it is a string, when in fact it is an array.  The comma isn't in the match, it is a separater.

The first element is:

```
(26 JAN 2011) - ILewis
```

The second is:

```
JAN
```

This is because you have the month bit wrapped in parentheses.  It is a capturing group and `exec` returns capturing groups as part of the result.

You want

```
sDate[0]
```

If you are getting an empty textbox from this, there is some other issue here outside of the regex.

*You also have some improperly escaped `\` in your regex.  As it is there, it does not work at all in IE.  You need `\\` wherever you have a `\`*

**EDIT**:  This fiddle shows the code in action.  It works.

http://jsfiddle.net/5azr9/

Comment: I understand that exec returns an array, but what I do not understand is why JavaScript interprets sDate[0] as "" rather than "(26 JAN 2011) - ILewis" sometimes.

Comment: Which \ is the improperly applied \ ?  For instance  I want \( because I want the '(' character.

Comment: Added a fiddle to the answer.  The code on its own works just find (after properly escaping the slashes). If it does not work for you, something else is going on.

Comment: You need to double escape because \ is an escape character in a js string as well as in the regex.  So \\ in the js string will put \ into the regex.

Comment: If parenthesis work and a capture group, is there a way emulate DD and (Month or Month) and YYYY behavior without making the months a capture group?  Thanks and sorry for all the questions.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it being a capture group, you just need to make sure you only take `[0]`.  Though you can add `?:` if you do not want it to capture.  http://jsfiddle.net/5azr9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get away with a simpler (more forgiving) regex, it all depends on your needs but try this:

```
/\(\d{2}.\w{3}.\d{4}\)[\s\-.,]{0,3}\b\w+\b/
```

Comment: I need it to be really unforgiving rather than fast.  Thanks for the idea though.